# Why multer undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Why multer after submit form always return value — undefined?

**app.js**

```
app.use('/post', routePost);
```

**Controller:**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './pubic/uploads')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
}

router.post('/create', upload.single('cover'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/post/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="cover" name="cover" type="file"  />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking, do you get a specific error, and are you posting all the code required to replicate the issue?

Comment: @Matthew No errors. I upload one photo to this controller. In the console value — undefined ;(

Comment: action="/post/create" & in controller - '/create'?

Answer (score 0):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, './pubic/uploads')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
}

const upload = multer({storage, limits: {fileSize: '2mb'},

router.post('/create', upload.single('cover'), (req, res) => {
console.log(req.file)
})
```

Comment: I updated the code. Check plz. I added a line app.js

Comment: add this code before router 
`const upload = multer({storage})`